# How to change the matrix display format in sage?

Tags: matrix, sage

When I use the following line on sage

`A=random_matrix(QQ,4,5,algorithm='echelonizable',rank=3,upper_bound=10); latex(A); A`

I get:

```
\left(\begin{array}{rrrrr}
1 & 1 & 7 & -4 & 7 \\
0 & 1 & 4 & -3 & 4 \\
0 & 2 & 9 & -6 & 9 \\
0 & 0 & -4 & 0 & -4
\end{array}\right)
[ 1  1  7 -4  7]
[ 0  1  4 -3  4]
[ 0  2  9 -6  9]
[ 0  0 -4  0 -4]
```

How can I get the following format instead?:

```
1 , 1 , 7 , -4 , 7 ;
0 , 1 , 4 , -3 , 4 ;
0 , 2 , 9 , -6 , 9 ;
0 , 0 , -4 , 0 , -4;
```

I thought that it could be an easy way to modify latex() however it is getting too hard to do. Maybe there is a way to get the desired display format without using latex().

Best,
Chilote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what program you are trying to emulate here - we have initializers for matrices in most scientific software you might want to import it into (Octave/Matlab, Mathematica, Maxima, Numpy, ...).  But [here is a hack from one of them](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJzzVbBVKErMS8nPjc9NLCnKrNCIitIx1jHW5OXy1YsvTs7MSUyKz8zLLInX0Iw2tNI1jAUAmHAPpg==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) that should work:

```
sage: M = random_matrix(ZZ,3,3)
sage: M._scilab_init_()[1:-1]
'-1,1,-2;11,0,5;-1,-19,1'
```

You *are* correct that you shouldn't try to mess with the latex function; better to do a search and replace or something in one of the existing methods.  Good luck.